# When assigning value to property 'a' of object I want property 'b' of same object to change (based on value property a)

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects

I want the value of the `.cName` property to automatically change whenever the `.c` property changes.

```
const NameList = {
    1: 'Once',
    2: 'Twice',
    3: 'Thrice'
}

// my new "class" object
function JimsObject(a, b, c, d) {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.cName = NameList[c];
    
}



var jimbo = new JimsObject();
jimbo.a = 48;
jimbo.b = "blah";
jimbo.c = 2;


console.log( jimbo.cName );
// Wanting output of 'Twice'
```

### I want the output/value to be `Twice`

Rather new to JavaScript... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What should happen if you set `cName`? Should it update `c`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving the function any parameters when executing it, thus they're all undefined and I'd assume you'd be getting some error in the construction of the class.

You have to pass the variables in the function parameters.

`var jimbo = new JimsObject(48, "blah", 2);` plus the 4th parameter `d` which you don't seem to be using anywhere though.

Also consider giving your variables more meaningful names!

Further on, considering using an array instead of an object! You'd have to start your index from 0 and up instead of 1 and up though.

`const NameList = [ "Once", "Twice", "Thrice" ];`

`NameList[0]` would return `Once`.

Comment: Thank you.  a) I am creating a new instance of an object (I hope, as that is my intention).  b) not getting any errors AND I am OK with some values being/remaining ```undefined```.  c) The above sample is minimal just to demonstrate what I am trying to do (my variables do have meaningful names).

Answer (score 0):

You can't listen to primitive value changes in javascript objects unless you use a proxy, which is kinda complicated to explain to a beginner, so the alternative is to use a setter function in your class.

You can do this:

```js
const NameList = {
    1: 'Once',
    2: 'Twice',
    3: 'Thrice'
    }

// my new "class" object
function JimsObject(a, b, c, d) {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.cName = NameList[c];
    
}

JimsObject.prototype.setC = function (value) {
   this.c = value;
   this.cName = NameList[value];
}


var jimbo = new JimsObject();
jimbo.a = 48;
jimbo.b = "blah";

jimbo.setC(2);


document.write(jimbo.cName);
// Wanting output of 'Twice'
```

You can also use `Object.defineProperty` to call a setter when changing the value of that property.

```js
const NameList = {
    1: 'Once',
    2: 'Twice',
    3: 'Thrice'
    }

// my new "class" object
function JimsObject(a, b, c, d) {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this._c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.cName = NameList[c];
    
}

Object.defineProperty(JimsObject.prototype, "c", {
  get: function() {
    return this._c;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this._c = value;
    this.cName = NameList[value];
  }
});


var jimbo = new JimsObject();
jimbo.a = 48;
jimbo.b = "blah";
jimbo.c = 2;


document.write(jimbo.cName);
// Wanting output of 'Twice'
```

Comment: `document.write()`?! DId I just go through a time portal and travel back to 1997?

Comment: @ScottMarcus thought it would be easier to see than console.log lol

Comment: Is there a reason you used a method instead of a property "setter" function.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for the `c` property.

```js
const NameList = {
  1: 'Once',
  2: 'Twice',
  3: 'Thrice'
}

// my new "class" object
function JimsObject(a, b, c, d) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  let cVal = c;
  let that = this;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'c', {
    get(){
      return cVal;
    },
    set(newVal){
      cVal = newVal;
      that.cName= NameList[cVal];
      return cVal;
    }
  });
  this.d = d;
  this.cName = NameList[c];
}



var jimbo = new JimsObject();
jimbo.a = 48;
jimbo.b = "blah";
jimbo.c = 2;


console.log(jimbo.cName);
```

You could also only define a getter for the `cName` property.

```js
const NameList = {
  1: 'Once',
  2: 'Twice',
  3: 'Thrice'
}

// my new "class" object
function JimsObject(a, b, c, d) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  let that = this;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'cName', {
    get(){
      return NameList[that.c];
    }
  });
  this.d = d;
}



var jimbo = new JimsObject();
jimbo.a = 48;
jimbo.b = "blah";
jimbo.c = 2;


console.log(jimbo.cName);
```

Comment: Or maybe just use `.c` directly in a getter for `cName`, like `return NameList[this.c]`

Comment: @slappy Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class jimObject

```js
const NameList = {
    1: 'Once',
    2: 'Twice',
    3: 'Thrice'
};

class JimObject {
    constructor(a, b, c, NameList){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.cName = NameList[c];
    }

    get name(){
        return this.cName
    }
}

let jimbo = new JimObject(48, 'blah', 2, NameList);

console.log(jimbo);
console.log(jimbo.name);
```